# Use list view with headers in a layout with margins

Tags: android, listview, layout, header, sections

I just started learning a little bit of Android. I am currently trying to use List Views with section headers. I found this reusable code at this website :

http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android

It uses two layout files: **snippet_item1.xml** and **snippet_item2.xml**.

The result looks like this:

[image: ListView with Section Headers]

I want this page to have a margin from the top of 100dp. I have tried adding margin_top and padding to both xml files but I don't get the desired results.

What do you think?

Comment: You want the whole thing to have a `margin_top` of 100dp? Just add that to the container viewgroup.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 There is no container here though. Both layouts are in a separate file and don't appear in a container anywhere. Am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: Dunno if you can do that with a `ListActivity` but try getting the list (it's id is `list`) and programatically add a margin. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extending from ListActivity, extend your class from a simple Activity and in that activity put a ListView, you can give margins and padding to ListView. Just use the same adapter you have already created with the ListView. Here is how.
This is your activity's layout file, call it activity_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="#fff">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:marginTop="20sp"
        android:marginBottom="10sp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:dividerHeight="5.0sp"
     ></ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now create an Activity in Java.

```
    public class MyListActivity extends Activity {
         private ListView listView;
         private MyAdapter myAdapter;
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
              this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
              this.myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext());
              //add whatever you want to add to your adapter
              listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
         }
    }
```

I hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Let me post this as an answer. I dunno if it's possible with `ListActivity`, though.

Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html for more details.

`ListActivity` adds a `ListView` to the layout with the ID `list`. You can try to grab that list and add the margin programatically.

```
@Override
public void onCreateView(...) {
    // set stuff up

    ListView lv = getListView();
    // set margin to lv
}
```

Setting padding/margin programatically is a little bit tricky for you'll have to pass pixels as argument but you want dp. But you can use `getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.style.youMarginStuffHere)` to handle that. Just add the margin to your *style.xml*.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with your method @m02ph3u5 but thank you for your effort.